# Multiple forms jquery validations with single validations functions

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

this is my validation function , it works fine when there is one form and when there are more than one form in single page its not working .

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("form").validity(function() {
            $("#name").require();
        });    
    });    
</script>
```

My forms are like

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="firstform">
<input type="text" id="name">
</form>
<form action="#" method="post" id="secondform">
<input type="text" id="name_othername">
</form>
```

can anyone give me suggestions, how to call the first form ids
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give both name-fields same class and instead of id you can call element by class. If you call specific form you can validate only that forms name-field:

```
$("#firstform").validity(function() {
    $(this).find(".name_class").require();
}); 

<form action="#" method="post" id="firstform">
<input type="text" id="name" class="name_class">
</form>
<form action="#" method="post" id="secondform">
<input type="text" id="name_othername" class="name_class">
</form>
```

Comment: this is not working, how can i call the selective form, form one or formn 2

Comment: see the edit. now function is referring exactly the first form by its id. Does this help?